# Atmosphere Framework : broadcaster broadcast message multiple times

Tags: java, sockets, long-polling, atmosphere

I'm current developping a simple chat multi-room based on this example :

https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-samples/blob/master/samples/chat-multiroom/

My development environment :

- Tomee Plus 1.7.2 server
- Atmosphere-runtime version 2.4.0
- Atmosphere-cdi version 2.4.0
- Java EE 1.7
- Long-polling protocol used

Before explaining my problem, here the global mechanism of chat room I have implemented :

1. User A is connected to the socket "chat/all". This socket allows to
   send ou receive any notifications between him and his interlocutor.
2. User A make a chat request from the first web app and wait for
   (pop-up spinner) a response from user B.
3. User B is also connected to the socket "chat/all". User B check
   every time, from the second web app, if there is a new chat request
   (SQL request from database). If he found a new request, he can or
   not accept this request.
4. User B accept chat request from user A. At this moment, throught
   socket "chat/all", user B push a message indicate he accepted this
   request. After that, user B is connected to the second socket
   "chat/1" (random id for specific chat room). He's waiting now
   (pop-up spinner like user B) for the user A to be connected to the same
   socket.
5. User A receive this message and is connect to the socket "chat/1".
   From server, user A is now connected to this chat room.
   There are two users in this chat room and I broadcast message to
   only user B to notify that user A is connected and close pop-up
   spinner.

**I have no problem when I broadcast message for just one resource. But when I broadcast message for two users, "onMessage" method is called multiple times !**

Here's my code about managing chat room :

```
@ManagedService(path = "/chat/{id_room}")
public final class ChatRoom {

 //many static final private attribute

 private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Chat.class);

 @PathParam("id_room")
 private String idChatRoom;

 private final static String CHAT = "/chat/";

 private final HashMap<Integer, List<String>> users = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();

 private Universe universe;

 private BroadcasterFactory broadcasterFactory = Universe.broadcasterFactory();

 private AtmosphereResourceFactory resourceFactory = Universe.resourceFactory();    

 private ChatMessageEncoderDecoder chatEncodeDecode = new ChatMessageEncoderDecoder();

@Message(encoders = { ChatMessageEncoderDecoder.class }, decoders = { ChatMessageEncoderDecoder.class })
 public final void onMessage(AtmosphereResource r, final ChatMessage message) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Integer chatRoomId = !NOTIFICATION_SOCKET_ALL.equals(idChatRoom) == true ? Integer.parseInt(idChatRoom) : 0;
    [...]
    if(...) {
        [...]
    }
    else {
        roomsList.add(idChatRoom);
        boolean messageEmpty = "".equals(message.getMessage());
        boolean chatConnectedWithTwoUsers = users.get(chatRoomId).size() > 1;
        boolean chatConnectedWithOneUser = users.get(chatRoomId).size() == 1;
            if(chatConnectedWithTwoUsers && MESSAGE_EVENT.equals(message.getEvent())) { //communication between two users to the chat room id
                Users user = CDIUtil.getBean(RechercheUserService.class).getUserChat(message.getMail());
                if(user != null){
                    try {
                        List<String> listUsersFromRoom = users.get(chatRoomId);
                        message.setUsers(listUsersFromRoom);
                        message.setEvent(MESSAGE_EVENT);
                        logger.info("{} a envoyé le message {}", message.getAuthor(), message.getMessage());

                        String messageToSend = chatEncodeDecode.encode(message);
                        broadcasterFactory.lookup(CHAT + idChatRoom).broadcast(messageToSend);

                        String messageUtf8 = new String(message.getMessage().getBytes(), "UTF-8");
                        CDIUtil.getBean(MessageRoomsService.class).createMessageContents(idChatRoom, user, messageUtf8);
                    } catch (IMException e) {
                        message.setEvent(MESSAGE_NOT_REGISTER_EVENT);
                        logger.error("Impossible d'enregistrer le message de l'utilisateur");
                    }
                }
                else{
                    message.setEvent(USER_NOT_EXIST_EVENT);
                    logger.error("Utilisateur Inconnu");
                }
            }
            else if(chatConnectedWithOneUser) { //two users connected to the chat room id
                users.get(chatRoomId).add(r.uuid()); 
                logger.info("L'utilisateur {} a rejoint le chat {}", r.uuid(), idChatRoom);

                AtmosphereResource resource = resourceFactory.find(users.get(chatRoomId).get(0)); //get the first user connected to the chat room

                List<String> listUsersFromRoom = users.get(chatRoomId);
                message.setUsers(listUsersFromRoom);
                message.setEvent(CHAT_COMPLETE_EVENT);

                String messageToSend = chatEncodeDecode.encode(message);
                broadcasterFactory.lookup(CHAT + idChatRoom).broadcast(messageToSend, resource);
            }
        }
   }
}
```

So, when broadcast is done, on interface user, there are 3 messages displaying. For example, User A send message "Hello, What can I do for you ?", User B see 3 times this message.

I think there are three messages because three resources are active on two socket. Indeed, the first socket "chat/all" is always active for one resource (user B) and the second socket "chat/1" is active for two resources (user A and user B). There are three resources.

Is there anyone who already face this problem ? Or is there anyone who have an idea about how to fix it ?

Comment: Hello, did you find any solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem too..I have resolved reading this link [Multiple messages arrive as single response body or message received are incomplete](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Multiple-messages-arrive-as-single-response-body-or-message-received-are-incomplete):

I have added to web.xml this init-param inside my Atmosphere Servlet

```
<init-param>
   <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereInterceptor</param-name>
   <param-value>org.atmosphere.client.TrackMessageSizeInterceptor</param-value>
</init-param>
```

and client-side I have added the `trackMessageLength : true` inside the request:

```
var request = { url: document.location.toString() + 'chat',
                contentType : "application/json",
                logLevel : 'debug',
                transport : 'long-polling' ,
                trackMessageLength : true,
                fallbackTransport: 'long-polling'};
```

As is reported in this link

> If you broadcast multiple messages and the underlying server buffer them in memory, your atmopshere.js callback or function can be invoked with multiple messages instead of a single message. It may not be an issue if you are using text, but if you are using JSON the parsing may fail because your callback/function gets invoked with multiple JSON messages.

I hope this will work also for you!